# getattr on a ctypes structure returns a handle and not a value

Tags: python, python-3.x, struct, structure, ctypes

The below code snippet seems to be returning a handle instead of a value while getting the c_int attribute of my ctypes structure.

How can the method get_val be changed to return the value of either o_num or o_str?

```
import ctypes

class my_struct(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_=[('o_num',ctypes.c_int),('o_str',ctypes.c_wchar_p),('o_bool',ctypes.c_int),('o_err',ctypes.c_int)]

class my_substruct(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_=[('rows',ctypes.c_int),('columns',ctypes.c_int),('next',ctypes.POINTER(my_struct))]

my_struct._fields_.append(('array',my_substruct))


class oper(ctypes.Union):
    _fields_=[('val',my_struct),('type',ctypes.c_wchar_p)]
    _mapping_={'num':'o_num','string':'o_str'}

    def get_val(self):
        return getattr(self.val,self._mapping_[self.type])

aa=my_struct(o_str='hello')
a=oper(aa,'string')
print(a.get_val())

bb=my_struct(o_num=33)
b=oper(bb,'num')
print(b.get_val())
print(bb.o_num)
```

and for some reasons i dont understand this returns

hello 
263314768 ===> this looks like a handle but WHY ???
33

Further to Mark's answer i've also tested with the below change:

```
class oper(ctypes.Union):
    _fields_=[('val',my_struct),('type',ctypes.c_int)]
    _mapping_={0:'o_num',1:'o_str'}
```

but this provides me with an equally weird result:

hello
0 ===> this is equally weird
33

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`oper` is declared as a Union, so `val` and `type` occupy the same memory.  When you create `b=oper(bb,'num')` both are written to the same memory location.  Only one will be correct.  What you see in `o_num` is probably the `c_wchar_p` pointing to the `'num'` string.

Comment: what do you mean while saying: "Only one will be correct"? Also, i've amended the code to try out your suggestion [if i understood it correctly], but i'm still getting an unexpected result. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Mark's answer, i realised that my problem was coming from the fact that Union [as opposed to Structure] uses a single memory space of the size of the biggest type in that Union. Structures on the other hand, allocates a dedicated memory space for each type in the structure. So, changing my Union to Structure does correct the problem and prevent this automatic casting from happening.